# What exactly does (&:id) do in Product.all.map(&:id)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, block, proc

Here's the line of code I'm trying to wrap my head around:

```
Category.all.map(&:id).each { |id| Category.reset_counters(id, :products) }
```

Hoping someone can help me understand what `(&:id)` is doing and how it impacts the rest of the line? I believe it turns the symbol `:id` into a **proc** that'll respond to `id`?!? But then it gets confusing...

Thanks in advance!

Comment: definitely a dupe. though hard to search for that... should have spelled it out "ampersand colon". (i can't delete; it has answers)

Comment: no worries, i searched for lambda operator shortcut rails

Comment: I much prefer this alternative: `Category.all.each { |cat| Category.reset_counters(cat.id, :products) }`

Comment: that's much easier, for me, to read!

Comment: @jvnill Why would you mark something as a duplicate of something that is itself a duplicate?

Comment: my bad. the first relevant SO result from google using "lambda operator shortcut rails" was that article.  I didn't go through the page itself. just copied the url from the google result.  i will have to be more careful next time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Category.all.map(&:id)
```

is shorthand for

```
Category.all.map { |a| a.id }
```

as for how it affects the rest of the line, the above section returns all `id` values as a single `Array`. This `Array` of ids is then passed into another call to `each`, which iteratively passes each id into `reset_counters`.